# 10 people flip a coin 12 times. What is the probability that at least one person gets 10 tails?

Tags: probability

I've already calculated the probability of getting 10 tails out of 12 flips:

$\frac{12!}{10! \times 2!} \times 0.5^{10} \times 0.5^{2}$

But I can't figure out how to calculate the probability of that at least one person  out of 10 gets 10 tails flipping a coin 12 times.

Comment: The probability of at least one person getting that is the $1-$ the probability of no one getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select a person then the probability that this person obtains the result is $\alpha$ for a certain value of $\alpha$ that you have already obtained.

Since people's results are independent between each other, the probability that none of them get the result is $(1-\alpha)^{10}$ and so the final result is $1 - (1-\alpha)^{10}$.